# Codeigniter and Facebook PHP SDK - error posting to user wall

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the FB PHP SDK to post a message to a user's wall.
Once the user is authenticated via FB I allow them to post a message using this helper function

```
function post_facebook($fb) {

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $CI->load->library('facebook');

    $config = array(
        'appId'  => '123123123123',
        'secret' => '567567567567'
    );

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $user_id  = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user_id) {

        $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array(
                                              'message' => $fb['post_text'],
                                           )
                   );
     }
}
```

This actually sends the post to FB and it **shows** on the wall.

But in Firebug I can see this error

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Missing argument 1 for Facebook::__construct(), called in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/system/core/Loader.php on line 1099 and defined</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Facebook.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 36</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: config</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Facebook.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 40</p>

</div>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error you see is from the call to `$this->load->library('facebook')`, you should pass the $config array as a parameter to it and access the library from the CI object, like this:

```
$config = array(
    'appId'  => '123123123123',
    'secret' => '567567567567'
);
$CI->load->library('facebook', $config);

$user_id  = $CI->facebook->getUser();
```

Read more about the loader here:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html